# How can I add a child to a node at a specific position?

Tags: xml, ruby, dom, nokogiri

I have a node which has two children: an HTML text and an HTML element.

```
<h1 id="Installation-blahblah">Installation on server<a href="#Installation-blah" class="wiki-anchor">&para;</a>
</h1>
```

In this case the HTML text is:

```
Installation on server
```

and the HTML element:

```
   <a href="#Installation-blah" class="wiki-anchor">anchor;</a>
```

I then create a node like this:

```
span_node = Nokogiri::HTML::Node.new('span',doc)
span_node['class'] = 'edit-section'

link_node = Nokogiri::HTML::Node.new('a',doc)
link_node['href'] = "/wiki/#{page_id}/#{@page.title}/edit?section=#{section_index}"
link_node['class'] = 'icon icon-edit'
link_node.content = 'mylink'

span_node.add_child(link_node)
```

Now, to add the above node to the main node I use the following:

```
node.add_child(span_node)
```

This appends the span node at the end. How can I put the `span_node` in front of all children?

Comment: For when I come back here from google, `Nokogiri::HTML::Node.new` throws error on recent version, instead use: `Nokogiri::XML::Node.new`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks Pesto for your almost correct solution.

The working solution is:

```
node.children.first.add_previous_sibling(span_node)
```

Comment: and if there are no children? I found a workround using a builder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596210/append-elements-using-nokogirixmlbuilder).

Answer (score 10):

`node.prepend_child span_node`

[Nokogiri::XML::Node#prepend_child Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode%3Aprepend_child)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`NodeSet#before`](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#M000248) like this:

```
node.children.before(span_node)
```

`NodeSet#before` is a short-cut method to insert an item as the first element.  A more general-purpose solution is to use [`Node#before`](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#M000290) and [`Node#after`](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#M000291).  For example, `some_node.before foo` will add the node `foo` as the sibling directly before `some_node`.  `Node#after` is similar.  Note that this:

```
node.children.first.before(span_node)
```

is thus equivalent to the solution above.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution adds only the content (in my case the XML Text mylink) in front of the children.

Comment: Works for me. Assuming there is at least one existing child.