# Append elements using Nokogiri::XML::Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following code:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.myRoot do |xml|
    xml.oneChild
    xml.anotherChild
  end
end
```

**Now I want to append a few child nodes to myRoot using the builder (in a second step, I know how to append them straight away). How can I do that?**

I've tried this:

```
node = builder.doc.xpath('//myRoot/oneChild').first
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(node) do |xml|
  xml.childOfOneChild 'Im a child of oneChild'
end
```

Which doesn't work. They won't stick to the element, it's just an empty oneChild.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code produces the following XML, which seems to meet your specifications. It doesn't produce an empty `oneChild`, at any rate. If this isn't what you're looking for, can you tell us what your ideal output would be?:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.myRoot do |xml|
    xml.oneChild
    xml.anotherChild
  end
end

puts builder.to_xml

# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <myRoot>
#   <oneChild/>
#   <anotherChild/>
# </myRoot>   

node = builder.doc.xpath('//myRoot/oneChild').first
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(node) do |xml|
  xml.childOfOneChild 'Im a child of oneChild'
end

puts builder.to_xml

# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <myRoot>
#   <oneChild>
#     <childOfOneChild>Im a child of oneChild</childOfOneChild>
#   </oneChild>
#   <anotherChild/>
# </myRoot>
```

Comment: I wonder, where the is the OP? this worked for me, thanks very much. documentation: http://rdoc.info/github/tenderlove/nokogiri/master/Nokogiri/XML/Builder/.with